# Uncaught type error: String is not a function only after second function call

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple shopping cart in js (just for show). I made a function to store objects in the cart, and each button will pass args to an "add to cart" function that makes a `CartItem` object with the parameters and stores than in the `cart` array. It works great the first time, but I get the `Uncaught type error: String is not a function` on the following line: `var a = new CartItem(title, price);`

Here's the relevant js:

```
var cart = [];
function CartItem(title, price) {
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.getTitle = function() {
        return this.title;
    };
    this.getPrice = function() {
        return this.price;
    };
}

function addToCart(title, price) {
    var a = new CartItem(title, price);
    cart.push(a);
    /* update cart display */
    for (CartItem in cart) {
        var itemDiv = document.createElement("div");
        itemDiv.className = "cartItem";
        itemDiv.innerHTML = title + " - $" + price;
        document.getElementById("cartDisplay").appendChild(itemDiv);
    }
}
```

and html:

```
        <div class="cartDisplay" id="cartDisplay">
            <p>All photographs are printed on 11"x17" Fujitsu Archival Quality stock.</p>
            <h3>Your Cart</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="storeGrid">
            <div class="storeItem">
                <img src="res/Photos/O_IMG_0002.jpg" class="storeImg"/>
                <div class="storeItemDesc">
                    <p>Price: $300</p>
                    <p>Description goes here.</p>
                    <a href="javascript:addToCart('Street with Steeple', 300, 1);" class="addToCart"><div class="addToCartDiv" id="1">Add to cart
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `for(CartItem in cart) {` smells funny to me. My guess is that JS is expecting a variable name where you have CartItem so it makes one in the global scope. Then when it tries to evaluate `var a = new CartItem(title, price);` CartItem is a global variable, not a constructor.

Anyway you shouldn't be using `for in` to loop over an array. You can do that in python or java, but in javascript it's for enumerating properties of an object. Use a standard loop instead.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)'s description of for..in:

> The for..in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.